# Get index in tableViewCells for tableView.visibleCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to make changes to the visible cells so that they reflect changes made to the underlying business object (object in an array correlated by the index of the cell in the table and the object in the array).

I just need to figure out the index or indexPath of the cell within the table.  So, if there are 10 cells and the bottom half were visible, then I'd need the value of 5 for first visible cell to correlate it to the same position in the array of article objects.

```
 for cell in tableView.visibleCells as! [ArticleTableViewCell] {
            //do something with the cell here.
           // var article = articlesList!.value![cell.index indexPath.item]
            cell.lblTitle.text = articleArray[5].title
}
```

Comment: What about doing `tableView.reloadData()` instead?

Comment: Just reload the visible cells instead of adding code that duplicates much of what you have in `cellForRowAt`. `tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows, animation: .fade)`

Comment: Exactly what I needed: tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView!.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none);
If you answer, I'll mark it as correct, rmaddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually iterating and updating the visible cells, you should tell the table view to reload the visible cells. This allows your existing `cellForRowAt` code to do its job without replicated the code elsewhere.

```
if let visibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
    tableView.reloadRows(at: visibleRows, animation: .fade)
}
```

Comment: The problem I am seeing with this approach is that when I do this, the list jolts when it calls reloadRows before re-appearing at its original state....

Comment: What do you mean by "jolt"? Do you mean it is scrolling back and forth a bit? Try different animation values such a `.none`. Or maybe it's a problem with row heights. Are your rows all the same height?

Comment: I'm using none.  Everything is the same height.